# Difference between 0,10 and */10 for crontab?

Tags: cron, crontab

I wanted to run a cron every 10 minutes.  What's the difference between the syntax `0,10` and `*/10`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0,10` will run the command on the 0 and 10th minute - so at 12:00, 12:10, 1:00, 1:10, etc. `*/10` will run the command every 10 minutes - 12:00, 12:10, 12:20, 12:30, etc.

Comment: I see... my bad

Comment: No worries - some more info can be found here http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: Another site with great explanation and expression builder: https://crontab.guru/